# How do I add commands to a class discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

For the last 2 years I have been using the discord.py class to write bots, but I wanted to make bots using a commands, but I want to stay on the class, tell me, is it possible to add commands to the class?

I tried to find information about this, but I did not find anything understandable.
What I want: To make commands work inside a class.

I would like something like this:

```
class Bot(discord.Client):

    async def on_ready(self):

        debug = self.get_channel(debug_channel_id)

        print("Bot ready")
        await debug.send("Bot ready")

        await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game("A game"))

    @commands.command()
    async def test(ctx, arg):
        await ctx.send("test command")
```

This is my first time posting here, so please forgive me if I did something wrong.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it impossible for you to add the command outside the class? Why do you need your command inside of it. I'm not 100% sure but I think you always need an instance, for example:

> bot = Bot()

before you can add a command.

You could make it work like:

```
class Bot(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix='.', intents=discord.Intents.all(), application_id=YOUR_APP_ID)

    async def on_ready(self):
        debug = self.get_channel(debug_channel_id)
        print("Bot ready")
        await debug.send("Bot ready")
        await self.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game("A game"))

bot = Bot()

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
    print(arg)
    await ctx.send(f"test command - you entered: **{arg}**")

bot.run('YOUR_TOKEN')
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I wanted, but it fits! Thanks for the help! I realized that the question was asked incorrectly :( I wanted to make the command inside the class, because it is convenient for me. Could you show how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same. This is the best I could come up with, but excited to see if anyone has a better alternative.

```
class DiscordClient(commands.Bot):
...:
def add_commands(self):
    @self.command(name="ping", description="lol")
    async def ping(ctx):
        await ctx.send("pong")


    @self.command(name="pong", description="lol")
    async def ping(ctx):
        await ctx.send("ping")
```

then in other classes you can just call the function to register:

```
client = DiscordClient()
client.add_commands()
```